# Google Font Importing Not Working in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, jsfiddle

Just for starters, I'm very new to WordPress. I've only been using it two days now, though I feel I have made decent progress. Anyways, I've tried to import the font Yellowtail into my theme on WordPress. I can't seem to get it to work, even when I test it in JSFiddle and verify that it works (link is http://jsfiddle.net/spvfoedz/). I read on [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432371/using-a-google-web-font-for-a-custom-wordpress-theme) that the issue can occur due to inheritance issues, but when I replace the imported font with something like cursive, it works.

And StackOverflow wants me to throw in some code, so I guess this helps even though it's the exact same thing on the page:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yellowtail:400");

.entry-title{
    font-family: cursive;
}
```

Comment: it works fine in fiddle, not sure what you need. Just in case, try using the link method `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yellowtail' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` and see if it works out for you

Comment: Wow. I didn't even notice a small class modifier three lines above my import. The import is now at the top of the line, and is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important

```
.entry-title{
    font-family: "Yellowtail" !important;
}
```

Comment: I just replaced my code with yours, but it still isn't working. It just goes back to using the standard font. You can check out the site at http://www.shawftware.net/